# Peculiar circumstance for my: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

Let's play...
        Click the Cat!

```
    <div id="bigBox" class="noselect">
        <div id="litterBox1" class="noselect">

        </div>

        <div id="clickBox" class="noselect">
            <div id="clicks1" class="noselect">Deuce</div>  
            <div id="clicks2" class="noselect">Mack</div> 
        </div>

        <div id="litterBox2" class="noselect">

        </div>
    </div>
```

(I have not been able to find a solution that was of similar to the context as with my Javascript.)

This is one of my first attempts at OO Javascript, and...

After many hawking, rewrites, and editing I still cannot determine what is causing the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null".

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var numClicks = 0;
var litterBox1 = document.getElementById("litterBox1");
var litterBox2 = document.getElementById("litterBox2");

var clickBox1 = document.getElementById("clicks1");
var clickBox2 = document.getElementById("clicks2");
var catName1 = "Deuce";
var catName2 = "Mack";


function Cat(catName, clickbox, litterBoxNum, numClicks){
    this.catName = catName;
    this.clickbox = clickbox;
    this.litterBoxNum = litterBoxNum;
    this.numClicks = numClicks;
}

Cat.prototype.cntClicks = function(){
    numClicks++;
    document.getElementById("letsPLay").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(this.clickbox).innerHTML = this.catName + " has " + this.numClicks + " cat-clicks!";
};



var deuce = new Cat(catName1, clickBox1, litterBox1, numClicks);
var mack = new Cat(catName2, clickBox2, litterBox2, numClicks);

catName1.onclick = deuce.cntClicks();
catName2.onclick = mack.cntClicks();
```

Comment: The element with the ID `letsPLay` is not existing in your example. (And also has a capital L). **edit:** You are also binding your functions to `onclick` property of your string variables(`catName1` & `catName2`), instead of the elements themselves!

Comment: @JeffNoel.  Yes, letsPlay element of the HTML was left out of what I posted.  AND, yes!  I'm not clicking anything.  ha.  Thanks for the fresh eyes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, but the one you are getting an error from is inside your `Cat.cntClicks` function. You are trying to access `innerHTML` property of the DOM element returned by the call to `document.getElementById` which can return null - which is actually returned in your case as `this.clickbox` passed as an argument to it is a DOM element itself and not an ID.

So, changing this line in the following way will fix your problem and lead you to the next one:-)

```
this.clickbox.innerHTML = this.catName + " has " + this.numClicks + " cat-clicks!";
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me, now.  And, your correction definitely corrected the original error.  However, I'm up against no errors and no action (click function is not working for whatever reason).  Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned seeing several problems with my code.  If you have the time to elaborate, that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems now that the cntClicks function is being automatically initiated upon window-load.  At which time, any further activity ceases altogether.

Comment: @eKimsey I guess the next step would be to assign click event handlers correctly, take a look at this documentation - http://devdocs.io/dom/eventtarget/addeventlistener BTW - you can thank me by upvoting the answer:-)